# Removing blank pages around "Parts" in Classicthesis

Tags: classicthesis

I'm wrapping up a classicthesis project and ran a bit over my allowed amount of pages. I noticed the template inserts a blank page before and after the title of and short introduction text to each "Part".

I've been studying \cleardoublepage in classisthesis.tex as well as the classicthesis.sty file, but can't seem to locate how to remove these blank pages - can anyone point me in the right direction?

Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the issue with a minimal example as I haven't yet understood how the complex layout architecture of Classicthesis with Parts, Chapters etc. comes together.

Answer (score 2):

`Classicthesis.sty` gets the part definition from the document class, presumably `book.cls`.  Book doesn't use `\cleardoublepage`, but what is does use is contained in `\@endpart`.

Note: this only removes the blank page after `\part`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage}
\makeatother

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\part{One}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your tips. How do I implement it - should I edit an existing file, create a new one or do something else... ?

Comment: Assuming you are using book class, just add the modified definition of \@endpart (including the \makeatletter...\makealother).  If you are using some other class...

Comment: I'll need to bother you a bit more with this - could you explain a bit more in detail how I can find out whether Classicthesis uses the book class? Classicthesis is, frankly, quite a complex jungle of files to navigate for someone not familiar with the logic of Latex.

Comment: Classthesis can be used with a number of different document classes.  You specify the document class in your document using \documentclass.